# Why does session object throw a null reference exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

on some of my aspx page I am checking session like this

```
if (bool.Parse(Session["YourAssessment"].ToString()) == false
    && bool.Parse(Session["MyAssessment"].ToString()) == true)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/myAssessment.aspx");
}
```

It works fine if I keep playing with the pages frequently, but if I don't do anything with the page at least even for 5 min, running the page throws the error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Following is the stack for this

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   yourAssessment.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Projects\NexLev\yourAssessment.aspx.cs:27
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Could some body explain me this weird behaviour?

And as we know by default the session last for is 20 min.

EDITED

See I have a page default aspx, it has got a button which fixes on the some basis where to redirect
On default page it check like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Session["YourAssessment"] = false;
        Session["MyAssessment"] = false;
    }
}
```

on button click it has

```
protected void imgClientFreeEval_Click(object sender,
    System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM SurveyClient WHERE UserID='"
            + cWebUtil.GetCurrentUserID().ToString() + "'";
        SqlParameter[] arrParams = new SqlParameter[0];
        int countSurvey = int.Parse(
            Data.GetSQLScalerVarQueryResults(sqlQuery).ToString());
        if (countSurvey > 0)
        {
            Session["YourAssessment"] = true;
            Session["MyAssessment"] = false;
        }
        Response.Redirect((countSurvey > 0)
            ? "~/yourAssessment.aspx"
            : "~/myAssessment.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
```

and on myAssessment page it check like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Session["YourAssessment"] != null
            && Session["MyAssessment"] != null
            && bool.Parse(Session["YourAssessment"].ToString())
            && !bool.Parse(Session["myAssessment"].ToString()))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/yourAssessment.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

and on yourAssessmtn it check like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Session["YourAssessment"] != null
            && Session["MyAssessment"] != null
            && !bool.Parse(Session["YourAssessment"].ToString())
            && bool.Parse(Session["MyAssessment"].ToString()))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/myAssessment.aspx");
        }

        PopulateAllSurveyByUser();
        if (ViewState["surveyClientID"] != null)
        {
            grdSurveyDetail.Visible = true;
            PopulateSurveyDetails(
                int.Parse(ViewState["surveyClientID"].ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            grdSurveyDetail.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong please explain?

Comment: because there are no "YourAssessment" or "MyAssessment" key in Session collection

Comment: ok my session getting null, but what action i shoud do if it's getting null?

Comment: well the best thing you can do is put value in session ;) just joking, where do you set session variables, show your code

Comment: let me explain my code above, wait..

Comment: @AntonioBakula: u see my code? it's posted on your demand...

Comment: There are cases when you don't set session values, I can't debug it for you, and that source posting is not my demand for me personaly, it's for you to solve your problem more quickly. On what page do you get exceptions ?

Comment: On yourAssessmen i get the error if i leave it idle for atleast 5 min..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You first need to check whether that session variable exists

```
if(Session["YourAssessment"] != null)
    // Do something with it
else
    // trying to call Session["YourAssessment"].ToString() here will FAIL.
```

That happens since your session has a lifecycle, which means - it expires (the cookie that defines it expires) - thus your objects vanish. you could increase  `sessionState timeout` in web.config for your sessions to last longer.

For example, in web.config

```
  <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="40" />
  </system.web>
```

Will make your sessions last for 40 minutes, as long as the client doesn't clear it, and the web server is up&running.

Comment: Even then browsers can clear sessions/cookies. Life is hard working with browsers.

Comment: @CodingBarfield, that why I mentioned *as long as the client doesn't clear it*

Comment: yes i understand it, but in my case i cleared it session.abandon on log out only..

Comment: ok my session getting null, but what action i shoud do if it's getting null?

Comment: You should go back to the main page or whereever you initiated your session variables.

Answer (score 3):

Always check for null when accessing Session object!
You can write some small utility that can be used for that:

```
public class SessionData
{
    public static T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];

        if(value == null)
            return default(T);

        try
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static void Put(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Session can be null if app pool is recycled. That can happen because numerous reasons...

One trick for keeping your server from loosing session is making "pings" to server from javascript. It can make requests to some dummy url (empty page, or if you're perf freak, to .ashx handler) every minute or so. It can be useful for pages that you keep open for long time, like huge edit forms.
Also, beware, there are different session timeout values for debug and release configuration!

Answer (score 1):

First you can use you code like this

```
if (!bool.Parse(Session["YourAssessment"].ToString()) && 
     bool.Parse(Session["MyAssessment"].ToString()))
    Response.Redirect("~/myAssessment.aspx");
```

You sure you Sessions are not `null`

Check like this

```
if (Session["YourAssessment"] != null && Session["MyAssessment"] != null && 
    !bool.Parse(Session["YourAssessment"].ToString()) && 
     bool.Parse(Session["MyAssessment"].ToString()))
        Response.Redirect("~/myAssessment.aspx");
```

Comment: But how can session be null in 5 mint

Comment: if you use improc session, maybe worker process on IIS is restarted

Comment: ok my session getting null, but what action i shoud do if it's getting null?

Answer (score 1):

If `Session` is not null, please recheck that it has key `"YourAssessment"` and `"MyAssessment"`.

Answer (score 1):

When your Session expires the objects you have placed in your session such as Session["YourAssessment"] become null and the .toString() method call on those objects will then throw an Object reference error.  To work around this you must first check to make sure your session variables being null before attempting to perform the toString().

```
    if(Session["YourAssessment"] != null){
if (bool.Parse(Session["YourAssessment"].ToString()) == false &&    bool.Parse(Session["MyAssessment"].ToString()) == true)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/myAssessment.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok my session getting null, but what action i shoud do if it's getting null?

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your question come through.  If you are getting null for "Your Assessment" then you best bet is to redirect to a custom error page and display an error to the user that indicates that they have not chosen an assessment.  Without knowing the full details of the app it's tough to say how it should be handled for sure but all applications should gracefully display errors to the user.  If you don't wish to display a specific error to the user then redirect or display an error on the page itself indicating that "there was an error" and log it for yourself somewhere meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the .ToString and Boolean.Parse do `Convert.ToBoolean(Session["YourAssessment"])`

When I try `Boolean b = Convert.ToBoolean(null)` b = false ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well after all that have been written about this it seems that problem is IIS application restarting and if your session is stored inproc that can couse deletion of session variables. So try to log application end events and see if this is a case, put this in Global.asax.cs application_end event, this code would log application restart and why it happened :

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpRuntime runtime = (HttpRuntime)typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null);

  string shutDownMessage = "";

  if (runtime != null)
  {
    shutDownMessage = Environment.NewLine + "Shutdown: " +
                      (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null) + 
                      Environment.NewLine + "Stack: " + Environment.NewLine +
                      (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null);
  }

  string logFile =  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(~/AppEndLog.log");
  string logMsg = "";
  if (File.Exists(logFile))
    logMsg = logMsg + File.ReadAllText(logFile) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
  logMsg = logMsg + Environment.NewLine + "ApplicationEnd - " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + shutDownMessage;
  File.WriteAllText(logFile, logMsg);


}
```